# Can't use CEC due to error using cec-client on 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I've been using CEC on Ubuntu for a good few years now on 14.04 and older I believe. However after upgrading to 15.10 on a fresh install, I am unable to set it up for XBMC.

What I am supposed to do is use the cec-utils package for the cec-client command. However, this doesn't work.

```
~$ cec-client
No device type given. Using 'recording device'
libcec.so.3.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load libcec.so
```

I've got both libcec3 and libcec-dev but neither work.

As you can see, I don't even get to the part to confirm whether my pulse-eight device is connected (which I have confirmed using lsusb) so I don't think it's due to that.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could solve it? I'm hoping that it's not just a matter of it not being supported yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. Rather than using the packages from the repositories, I tried compiling it myself.

This was one of the solutions I attempted before but I'm assuming now that I did something wrong. I'm guessing that I forgot to remove one of the packages and there was conflict or I missed out the last command here.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake liblockdev1-dev libudev-dev libxrandr-dev python-dev swig
cd
git clone https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/platform.git
mkdir platform/build
cd platform/build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
cd
git clone https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec.git
mkdir libcec/build
cd libcec/build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

If this doesn't work for anyone else with the problem, check if they still have the libcec3 package installed. I may be wrong, but I think this won't work if there is already the libcec package.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be fixed by creating a symlink for the missing library:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcec.so.3.0.1 /usr/local/lib/libcec.so.3.0
sudo ldconfig
```

It worked for me on Ubuntu 15.10 x86_64.